# Querystring filter for PerformancePoint

Tags: sharepoint-2010, dashboard, performancepoint

Keep in my I am using Dashboard Designer, SharePoint 2010 and PerformancePoint Server 2010.

I have a dashboard homepage showing a KPI for sales, by brand. I added a custom property "View detailed report" on my KPI. When I click on that, I want to be able to go to a second dashboard page featuring 5 scorecards and 2 reports for my sales, by brand. The brand needs to be a filter.

Obviously, what I wanted to do is to tell my second page on which brand to filter by using a querystring parameter, something like ?BrandFilter=[Brand].[X].[Y] ...

But, in Dashboard Designer, you cannot (?) have querystring based parameters. I know I can do it directly in SharePoint (with the corresponding web part), but then when I deploy my dashboard again, I lose custom changes I do to my pages.

I tried to create a custom transform for scorecards that would read the querystring and add PageFilters, but I faced two problems:
1. I cannot access the HttpContext from there (of couse!)
2. That would not do it for reports.

What should I do? Drop Dashboard Designer and work directly in SharePoint? I wish there is a solution with Dashboard Designer!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do that. I customized my scorecard generation (using C#) and added a javascript method to my master page to handle all the links that are clicked. When I click on a link in a scorecard, I get the parameter from the current URL and update a filter inside the page with that. I can share more details on request...